# Return the first occurance of a certain string length using itertools in Python

Tags: python

I'm generating fibonacci sequence numbers using a generator in python (Generator works fine)

**The problem is that I can't figure out how to get the first *n*-digit variable and to print it.**

```
print list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: len(str(x))<=3,fib_function()))
```

will return

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987]
```

- **In other words, it returns all three digit terms, which is unnecessary since I only wanted up to and including 144.**  Limiting it to two will not generate the next one which I would need, and I don't seem to be able to trick it into doing just one more iteration.
- Furthermore, this code will print the entire sequence, not just the last occurance. I've had a look through the docs but it dosen't seem to suggest anything. I can live with it but it would be nicer if it did.

*(Note: This is project euler problem 25: generate the first 100-digit fibonacci number)*

Comment: Any specific reaon on why you need to use itertools? a simple while loop should work fine too

Comment: @vz0 stood under the impression that it was faster,no?

Comment: IHDK, you should measure it. Remember that Euler programs are mostly throwaway code that you write just for solving that specific excercise. The simpler is the program, the better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch to [`itertools.dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) to skip everything under 3 digits, then take the *next* value after that with `next()`:

```
print next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x < 100, fib_function()))
```

I changed the digits test to test for 100 instead; this saves you 2 function calls.

Demo:

```
>>> print next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x < 100, fib_function()))
144
```